# Difference between "addi" and "add" for pseudoinstruction "move" in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, addition, mips, move

For this pseudoinstruction:

`move $rt, $rs`

Are both the addi and add assembly code acceptable? So could I use either

`add $rt, $rs, $0`

or

`addi $rt, $rs, $0`

?

Edit: 
I think I made a mistake with `addi`

`add $rt, $rs, $0`

would be the same as

`addi $rt, $rs, 0`

since `add` adds registers, and I need a constant for the immediate for `addi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addi` instruction requires an *immediate* operand rather than a register, so the `$0` would actually be `0`:

```
add   $rt, $rs, $0
addi  $rt, $rs, 0
```

Both will *work* and have all the needed information encoded into the instruction itself):

```
add   $d, $s, $t
    0000 00ss ssst tttt dddd d000 0010 0000
addi  $t, $s, i
    0010 00ss ssst tttt iiii iiii iiii iiii
```

However, it would be more *usual* to just use the zero-locked `$0` register in this particular case since that is, after all, its purpose.

I would also tend to use the unsigned variant however, since I seem to recall there may be extra overflow checking done for signed instructions:

```
addu  $rt, $rs, $0
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I thought so. I edited my question to reflect this just as you answered, but I understand now.

Comment: Are there any performance benefits to using one instruction rather than the other?

Comment: @YuChen, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249629/mips-amount-of-cycles-for-i-type-instructions-addi